# Add Option menu on Runtime Android

Tags: android, menu

My app has to show one option in Menu, depending on the permission of the user.

the item in menu is like:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_waittime"
    android:visible="false"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_waittime"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

and when the activity launch, will be by default disabled. Then in oncreate() I IQ request is done:

```
mConnection.subscribeIQResponseFromNamespace(this, NAMESPACE);
        WaitTimeIQ waitTimeIQ = new WaitTimeIQ();
        //waitTimeIQ.setFrom(mConnection.getUser());
        try {
            waitTimeIQ.setTo(JidCreate.from("chvcomponent.chv.cat"));
        } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        waitTimeIQ.setType(IQ.Type.get);
        mConnection.sendIQMessage(waitTimeIQ);
```

After that I'll receive the permission answer. IF the response is "granted" I have to show the option.

I do this:

```
public void activeOption(string autho) {   
    if (autho.equals("granted")) {
        Menu mMenu = mToolbar.getMenu();
        mMenu.getItem(R.id.action_waittime).setVisible(true);
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
}
```

But, it is not refreshed and not showed.

How can I manage to make it visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity

```
private Menu menu;
```

In onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

```
this.menu = menu;
```

and then in

```
public void activeOption(string autho) {   
    if (autho.equals("granted")) {
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_waittime);
        item.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, just with a few configurations, because the response can arrive before the `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` is called. so I had to validate if `menu!=null` in `activeOption(..)` and active a flag if is it, to do it `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. Just to allow if respnse arrive before or after is printed due , server Lag. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to (or at least can) set the visibility in the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` within the activity.

As an example:-

```
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem reviewdisabledsuggestions = menu.findItem(R.id.reviewdisabledsuggestions);

        /**
         * Enable Review Disabled Rule Suggestions only if some rules are disabled
         */
        if(shopperdb.getDisabledRuleCount() > 0 ) {
            reviewdisabledsuggestions.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            reviewdisabledsuggestions.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
```